# Test for significant difference between two groups over time

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, descriptive-statistics

I have two different species of chicken in my chicken farm: species A and B.

I have 60 chicken of species A and 60 chicken of species B.

Over a three month period I wish to investigate whether they gain weight differently.

I do 5 weight measuring samples during the three month period. On each sampling day I will measure the weight of 12 chicken from species A and 12 chicken from species B.

On each sampling day, I weigh and note the weight of each 12 chicken from species A and B.

I do the same for all 5 sampling sessions until I am left with no more chickens.

Now, I wish to investigate whether species A and B gain weight(g=grams) differently during the three months. And, if these weigth differences differ with statistical signficance .

I am new to statistics, so any help would be much appreciated.

[image: and so on...]

Comment: I assume the chickens being weighed are removed, since you write «until there are no more chickens». This removes the possibility of tracking any one chicken. Weird set-up, but interesting how to solve it...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The weighed chickens had to be slaughtered after each weighing session, that is correct.   inoptimal set-up, yes, but the only way it could be done.  Sorry vegans